# Paypal_lib for CodeIgniter 2.x.x

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I cant seem to the find where to download the Paypal_lib. Has it been updated for CodeIgniter 2.x.x?

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to use AIO lib in your CI then here is the another library that come with

- 2Checkout
- Authorize.Net AIM
- Authorize.Net SIM
- DPS PaymentExpress PxPay
- DPS PaymentExpress PxPost
- eWay Direct
- eWay Shared
- GoCardless
- iDEAL
- Manual
- Payflow Pro
- **PayPal Express Checkout**
- **PayPal Website Payments Pro**
- SagePay Direct
- SagePay Server
- Stripe
- WorldPay
- and more

CI-Merchant is a driver-based payment processing library built specifically for use in CodeIgniter web applications. It allows you to integrate any supported payment gateway using a consistent API.

http://ci-merchant.org/

Answer (score 0):

here is the link you find the [**Codeigniter paypal IPN**](https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn)

Or here is another link   [**codeigniter paypal**](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/paypal-library-for-php-codeigniter-framework)

Answer (score 0):

**Here it is:**

**https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter**

**Another recommended library:**

**[CodeIgniter PHP Library for PayPal Payments](http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/)**